# Como especificar os arquivos que quero adicionar à área de stage?

Tags: git

Por exemplo, estou trabalhando em uma branch x.

Alterei os seguintes arquivos 1,2,3,4. Rodei o git status apareceu tudo certo. Até aí tudo ok!

Se eu rodar o `git add .` irá adicionar os 04 arquivos.

Como faria para add apenas os arquivos 1, 2 e 3 deixando o 4 de fora?

Answer (score 3):

O `.` (ponto) no `git add` (nas versões 2.x do GIT) diz que você quer adicionar em *stage* **todas as modificações** que foram feitas (todos os novos arquivos, todos arquivos modificados e tudo que foi deletado).

Especifique os arquivos no `git add`

```
git add 1 2 3
```

Comment: Ok, farei o teste aqui. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você tambem pode usar algumas ide de desenvolvimento para facilitar esses processos.

Por exemplo no [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download),abaixo voce seleciona o arquivo que quer adicionar em stage ao clicar no + :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E abaixo voce coloca a mensagem do seu commit:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clicando na setinha de correto, você efetua seu commit. e clicando em - você remove o arquivo que adicionou em stage.

Se você clicar no simbolo de sincronismo, é possivel dar pull e push, os comandos sao usados nessa ordem, assim não sobrepondo mudanças feitas na branch

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Uma possivel solução é usar como parametro do `git add` o resultado de uma subshell que ao listar o diretorio ignore certos arquivos. Exemplo `git add $(ls -I 4)`. É possivel ignorar listas de arquivos por extensão, `git add $( ls -I "*.h" "*.c")`.